# Passcode functionality for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was thinking about putting in PIN number functionality within my iPhone app (various examples can be seen here http://forums.mint.com/showthread.php?t=5956 ), but I was kinda stumped how to go about it. Should I just go with a hidden textfield and simulate the inputs with images?

Comment: Here: http://www.binpress.com/app/passcode-lock-view-for-ios/904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10860-how-do-i-replicate-passcode-screen.html